# How would I place and center a logo between 2 lists in the bootstrap 3 navbar?

Tags: image, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

```
<body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
  <div class="navbar-inner" style="position: center;">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cottages</a></li>
  </ul><a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/150x150"></a>
   <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="#">Attractions</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Here's my code. I'm trying to put the brand in between the "Cottages" and "Attractions" links and center everything horizontally while keeping the layout responsive. Plus, I want the brand to extend vertically outside the navbar (existing without changing the height of a navbar).
If there is a better way to do this (rather than the HTML I have now) please let me know! Thank you.

Edit: here's a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JKsJU/) with my current code. Although I must say that the code results differently in my browser...

Answer (score 0):

Use a wrapper class:

```
#wrapper { 
  margin:0 auto; 
  width:500px;
}
```

Apply this like this.

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <nav> </nav> 
</div>
```

if you need to resize it on a specific size based on a view-port you may need to use css @media Queries to alter the css based on a specific width.

Comment: This unfortunately didn't work for me :( Thanks for your reply!

Comment: Can you provide a jsfiddle with some css to help you out

Comment: Sure! There ya go mate